# Is there any way to read Qt qsetting config file using other language like c#?

Tags: qt

QSettings encode variants in their own way which I think it's stupid because you can't share the config file with other programs which are not written in Qt. And I can't find any document showing how QSetting encodes variants.

Comment: Then properly convert your custom QVariant type to a string before writing it to the ini file.

Comment: QSettings uses serialization implemented by operator<< that returns QDataStream&.
You can write your own serialization method (like something that returns a QString) and read/write using your own method.
It's not really stupid. For example you won't expect Qt to support protobuf serialization/deserialization by nature.